# The TLB changes whenever a program does a context switch?

Tags: memory, cpu

If the TLB gets flushed everytime a program does a context switch, then when that program is run again, where does the TLB go to reload its table? Also, if the table gets flushed, then how are other programs prevented from writing into memory that belongs to that program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts out empty and is reloaded as accesses occur.

The TLB is an optimization that avoids reading slower page table information to locate application memory; in particular, memory access control is done form the page tables, not the TLB.

And the reason you clear it is two-fold:  because if you didn't, accesses from the next process might go to your process's memory (the exact opposite of your presumption!), and because it could conceivably be used to snoop on your process's memory and/or activity.

Comment: I read in a book that the TLB has its own table, and it only goes to the page table only if nothing is found in its own table.

Answer (score 1):

The TLB is reloaded from the page table. The page table always has the up-to-date mapping.

Like a processor cache, the TLB is just a copy of what is there in the page table, so there is no information loss from flushing it. Also, even if TLB is flushed, the memory of one program is not allocated to other programs, so they cannot write to this program's memory.

See my [survey paper on TLBs](https://www.academia.edu/29585076/A_Survey_of_Techniques_for_Architecting_TLBs) for more detailed understanding of the topic.